# create task from another task - deadlock when replace std::async with thread pool libraries

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++14, deadlock

Here is a nice working multi-thread code.  It uses `std::async` :-

[image]

```
class C{  public: int d=35;  };
class B{
    public: C* c;
    public: void test(){
        std::vector<std::future<void>> cac;
        for(int n=0;n<5;n++){
            cac.push_back(
                std::async(std::launch::async,[&](){  
                    test2();
                })
            );
        }
        for(auto& ele : cac){
            ele.get();
        }
    };
    public: void test2(){
        std::vector<std::future<void>> cac;
        for(int n=0;n<5;n++){
            cac.push_back(
                 std::async(std::launch::async,[&](){  
                    int accu=0;
                    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                        accu+=i;
                    }
                    std::cout<<accu<<" access c="<<c->d<<std::endl;
                })
            );
        }
        for(auto& ele : cac){
            ele.get();
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the test case :-

```
int main(){
    C c;
    B b; b.c=&c;
    b.test();
    std::cout<<"end"<<std::endl;
}
```

It works, but if I change from `std::async` to use thread-pool library e.g.

- **Progschj's ThreadPool** (https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h)

  ```
  ThreadPool pool(4);
  ...
  pool.enqueue([&](){  
      test2();
  })
  ```
- **vit-vit's ctpl** (https://github.com/vit-vit/CTPL/blob/master/ctpl_stl.h)

  ```
  ctpl::thread_pool pool(4);
  ...
  pool.push([&](int threadId){  
      test2();
  })
  ```

... I will encounter either access violation or freeze (presumably, dead lock).

### Question

Does it mean I can't create a task from another task?
Which part of code is the cause of the restriction?    How to overcome it?

Here are all 3 MCVE.
[std::async (Coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0f313f9fbcc7943) , [Progschj's ThreadPool (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/ypKyy6Bm), [ctpl (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/S3J8yFrC).

I have tried to dig into their library, but with my limited experience, I can't  find the cause.

### Clue

In real-case, the error tends to happen when amount of task > amount of thread (4).
Sometimes, it causes unrelated-library's thread to halt forever. (e.g. SDL keyboard listener.)

In a more complex program, Visual Studio sometimes catch `this (B*) = 0x02`.
(I guess the reference to `this` is removed after a-lambda-with-capture is used  once in a loop; out-of-scope??)

Here is the most suspicious location in **ThreadPool** (both library are very similar):-

```
// add new work item to the pool
template<class F, class... Args>
auto ThreadPool::enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) 
    -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>
{
    using return_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;

    auto task = std::make_shared< std::packaged_task<return_type()> >(
            std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        );

    std::future<return_type> res = task->get_future();
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);

        // don't allow enqueueing after stopping the pool
        if(stop)
            throw std::runtime_error("enqueue on stopped ThreadPool");

        tasks.emplace([task](){ (*task)(); });
    }
    condition.notify_one();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The general rule is that in a thread pool you cannot just wait for another task in the thread pool to complete, because there may be no other thread available other than yours, and you are hanging it waiting for stuff that will never get done. Each task must eventually make progress on its own, irrespective of the scheduling of the other tasks. A strategy I used in the past to have "recursive tasks" was to make the "waiting" thread do enqueued work for the thread pool while waiting for the subtasks to complete, thus guaranteeing progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deadlock comes because the tasks in the ThreadPool cannot be preempted. Hence if you recursively call the `ThreadPool::enqueue` method and afterwards wait for the result you end up in the deadlock because all the threads are used and cannot execute the newly enqueued tasks.

A little more detailed:
Let's go through your code step by step.
1. You call `B::test()` this function enqeues 5 tasks in the thread pool and later waits for their result, i.e. for them to finish, in `ele.get()`.
2. The threads in the thread pool deque one of those tasks (enqued in step 1), which means if the amount of threads <= the amount of tasks, all of the threads execute `B::test2()`. Here again you enqueue 5 new tasks in the thread pool.
3. Now comes the critical point. Later in `B::test2()` you wait for the result of those tasks by `ele.get()`, which means the threads of the thread pool are blocked, until the tasks (the ones with the for loop) have been executed and their result was saved in the `std::future`. But as the threads of the thread pool are blocked, they cannot execute tasks any more. Hence the currently running tasks wait for the execution of the other tasks, which will never be executed because all the threads are blocked ==> deadlock.

Comment: @Matteo Italia (and Mike van Dyke) :-  Do you mean deadlock come from `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);`?  I believe it just `tasks.emplace()`.  That means it just adds a task (i.e. function pointer) to a queue.   It does not actually wait until the function itself `(*task)()` finish, does it?

Comment: We mean the wait inside `ele.get();` in `test2`. `test2` runs in threads in the thread pool, and you are hanging all of them waiting for the subtasks to complete - but they cannot complete, as all the threads of the thread pool are hung in that `get()`. You don't have that problem with "regular" `std::async` because in that case subtasks run in their own threads, which can be scheduled without problems.

Comment: @cppBeginner Matteo Italia has the point. I edited my previous post.

Comment: @Matteo Italia (and Mike van Dyke) Thank. I understand it now.  Can I overcome such limitation? I want to create thread from a thread like the graph.  I dream to create a highly-customizable multithread controller.

Comment: @cppBeginner Not with the thread pools you used in your question. But there are some larger frameworks that support a wait function for their tasks (the wait function basically just executes tasks in the wait queue of the thread pool). Take a look at Embedded Multicore Building Blocks or Intel Threading Building Blocks. But those frameworks are really large. Don't know if you want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I hope its useful. Some time ago I developed a small but effective [threadpool library](https://github.com/amc176/cpp-threadpool).
With little modifications, I have tested your use case and it seems to work great, so maybe you could give it a look.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/724b82bee178f90f). (Sorry for the size, I had to include all the library code inside to test it with your example)